# useEffect inside custom hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-custom-hooks

I know that in case of react components the function inside useEffect will run after the component has been rendered. When exactly does it run if the useEffect is inside a custom hook?
As a more generic question when do the codes inside a custom hook run when the component using the hook is (re)rendered?

Answer (score 0):

In React, when a component using a custom hook is rendered or re-rendered, the code inside the custom hook runs just like any other function in JavaScript. The useEffect hook inside the custom hook will also run after the component has been rendered, just like when it is used directly inside a component.

To be more specific, the code inside the custom hook will run every time the component using the hook is rendered or re-rendered. This is because the custom hook itself is just a function that is called every time the component is rendered. The useEffect hook inside the custom hook will also run every time the component is rendered or re-rendered, based on the dependencies specified in the useEffect hook.

It's important to note that the behavior of the custom hook may depend on the state and props passed into it by the component, so the code inside the custom hook may run differently depending on the inputs to the hook.

Comment: Just to be sure, does the custom hook remember the last dependency value (e.g []) for each re-render of the component or is it just reset and useEffect will run anway?

Comment: Yes, it does remember all the dependency values inside ([]).

Answer (score 0):

The code inside a custom hook will be executed whenever the component using the hook is rendered, just like any function.

However, the behavior of useEffect hooks remains the same, i.e. they are only executed when the dependencies specified in their dependency array change.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

```
function useCustomHook() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect inside custom hook");
  }, [count]);

  const incrementCount = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  return { count, incrementCount };
}

function App() {
  const { count, incrementCount } = useCustomHook();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect inside App");
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={incrementCount}>Increment Count</button>
      <p>Count: {count}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's remove the custom hook from the picture for a second, and just assume all the logic that you have inside your custom hook is directly part of the component using that hook. In that case the useEffect will initially run when the component mounts and then after that if any of the dependencies of the useEffect gets changed, it will run again, in a nutshell useEffect will behave the way it is intended to. This intended behavior will have no impact if you just pick the useEffect and put it in a custom hook and use the custom hook instead of the effect directly in your component. The custom hook will definitely be called each time your component using the hook re-renders but the effect will only be ran inside the custom hook if any of the effect's dependencies has changed.